# multiple pivottables from the same pivotchache error

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm getting an error "Application-defined or object-defined error" when trying to add a second pivottable to the same pivotcache. The code runs on a different workbook than the one where the pivottables are created. (Excel 2016)

```
Public Sub exportFA()

    Dim ExportWbk As Workbook
    Dim sExportPath As String
    Dim sTargetWS As Worksheet
    Dim oFAConn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pc As PivotCache


    'connect to an existing excel workbook. It has an excel table that will be the source for pivots.
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show = -1 Then
        'copy file path to text box
        sExportPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    If Trim(sExportPath) = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set ExportWbk = Workbooks.Open(sExportPath, False, False)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set sTargetWS = ExportWbk.Sheets.Add(After:=ExportWbk.Worksheets(ExportWbk.Worksheets.Count))
    sTargetWS.Name = "FinancialAnalysis"

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    'Create a workbook connection to an excel table
    Set oFAConn = ExportWbk.Connections.Add2( _
        "FA_Connection", "", _
        "WORKSHEET;" & sExportPath _
        , ExportWbk.Name & "!tblCombinedAccounting_FA", 7, True, False)

    'Create the pivot cache to be used by the FA tables
    Set pc = ExportWbk.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=oFAConn, Version:=6)

   'Setup first pivot. This works fine.
   Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ExportWbk.Sheets("FinancialAnalysis").Range("C3"), 
   TableName:="ptFA_1", DefaultVersion:=6)

   Call SetupPivot(pt,1) 'setup the fields of the pivot. This is irrelevant as skipping it and placing the second pivot table somewhere else on the sheet still raises an error

   '!!!!!!this raises the error
   Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ExportWbk.Sheets("FinancialAnalysis").Range("C" & 
   pt.RowRange.End(xlDown).Row + 10), TableName:="ptFA_2", DefaultVersion:=6)

   ' I also tried a different add method, but I get the same error:
   Set pt = ExportWbk.Sheets("FinancialAnalysis").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=pc, TableDestination:=ExportWbk.Sheets("FinancialAnalysis").Range("C100"), TableName:="ptFA_2")
```

Comment: Approximately what does TableName:="ptFA_1" look like after it has been created?  what are its dimensions?  are we getting overlap when we try table 2?

Comment: The build of it is not the issue. I can leave it empty right after creating it (ie. skip the call to SetupPivot) and attempt to add the second one several rows below, say C100, and I'll still get this error

Comment: What data would I need to replicate the failure? Could you post that?

Comment: You should include in your post this procedure `SetupPivot(pt,1)`

Comment: I didn't provide SetupPivot, because I can remove this call and still get the error with default (unbilt) pivottables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when adding `PivotTables` to the `Data Model` a `PivotCache` needs to be created for each `PivotTable`. To test this manually create two `PivotTables` from the same `Table` while recording a macro. Ensure to check the box `Add this data to the Data Model` or `Use this workbook's Data Model`. You'll see in the recorded macro that in both cases a `PivotCache` is created, however both `PivotTables` can be *"controlled"* by a common `Slicer`.

**Proposed solution:**
This solution applies to `PivotTables` to be Added to the `Data Model`.

```
Public Sub PivotTables_Add_ToDataModel()
Const kCntNme As String = "Cnt_DataModel"   'Connection Name
Const kConnct As String = "WORKSHEET;#PTH"  'ConnectionString
Const kCmdTxt As String = "#WBK!#TBL"       'CommandText
Dim sPath As String
Dim Wbk As Workbook
Dim Wsh As Worksheet
Dim Cnt As WorkbookConnection
Dim Ptb As PivotTable

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show = -1 Then
        sPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
        If Trim(sPath) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath, False, False)
    With Wbk
        
        Set Wsh = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        Wsh.Name = "FinancialAnalysis"
    
        Rem Set DataModel Connection
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Cnt = .Connections(kCntNme)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Cnt Is Nothing Then
            Set Cnt = .Connections.Add2(kCntNme, kCntNme, Replace(kConnct, "#PTH", sPath), _
                Replace(Replace(kCmdTxt, "#WBK", .Name), "#TBL", "tblCombinedAccounting_FA"), xlCmdExcel, True, False)
        End If
    
        Rem Set 1st PivotTable
        Set Ptb = .PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=.Connections(kCntNme), Version:=6) _
                    .CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Wsh.Range("C3"), TableName:="ptFA_1", DefaultVersion:=6)
        
        Rem Set 2nd PivotTable
        Set Ptb = .PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=.Connections(kCntNme), Version:=6) _
                    .CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Wsh.Range("C100"), TableName:="ptFA_2", DefaultVersion:=6)
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is interesting. It works but the pivot table then is not using the data model, which is something I need. When using the worksheet connection, my table is added to the model. Any other way to add multiple powertables to powercache that's connected to a table in a data model?

Comment: Should have mentioned that these were PivotTables added to the Data Model. Adapted the answer for `PivotTables` added to the `Data Model'. Please test and let me know the outcome.

Comment: Thank you EEM. This is great. Works as advertised!